# Three-column layout with block of different heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple 3-column layout based on Twitter Bootstrap. The only problem is, that each column is assembled from block with different heights.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="blocks" class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="block" id="block1">
            <div class="block" id="block4">
            <div class="block" id="block7">
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="block" id="block2">
            <div class="block" id="block5">
            <div class="block" id="block8">
        </div>            
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="block" id="block3">
            <div class="block" id="block5">
            <div class="block" id="block9">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: This way].

It works quite fine, except for small displays. Then the order of blocks is not sorted.

[image: On small displays]

Is there some way to achieve sorted blocks without any JavaScript?

Comment: Are the different heights fixed? In other words, can the heights be hardcoded in the css (or an inline style), or do the blocks need to adjust their size based on content?

Comment: No, it is based on content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this effect with the 3 column structure. If the blocks were all the same height then you could float:left all the blocks without the columns then they would wrap in order. Since they are not the same size you would have to use a JavaScript such as masonry:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Its gonna be quite difficult to achieve this, you might wanna play around with single list with float: left; or display: inline-block;

or

you can have 2 set of list with @media inside the css, so depend on the screen size you can show or hide the selected div

css example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
.displayFullScreen {display: block;}
.displayMobileScreen {display: none;}
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.displayFullScreen {display: none;}
.displayMobileScreen {display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to use `column-count: 3;` and `column-gap: 10px;`. But order is **different** on wide screen.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksvx2txb/102/