# Responsive 3 columns layout with different height blocks

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

I would like to build a responsive 3-columns layout. For large screens I have 3 columns, reduced to 2 for medium and to 1 for small screens. Blocks contain text, so they have different height. My goal is to create a line of blocks aligned to the top (this illustration refers to 3-columns layout but principle is valid for 2-columns too).

[image: My goal]

But my best result is the following

[image: My best result]

Pretty different, yes. I think the problem is that I am not able to create virtual "lines" of blocks, where I can align 1-2-3 and 4-5-6 to the top. Here is my code (I haven't posted it on jsfiddle because effect can be noticed better on wide screens).

HTML

```
<div class="span3">
<b>ONE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>TWO</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque interdum risus nulla, ac tristique dolor tincidunt consequat. Nunc malesuada pharetra scelerisque.
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>THREE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>FOUR</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>FIVE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque interdum risus nulla, ac tristique dolor tincidunt consequat. Nunc malesuada pharetra scelerisque.
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>SIX</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.span3 {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:951px)
{
    .span3 {
        width:31%;
        margin-left:3.5%;
    }

    .span3:nth-child(3n+1) {
        margin-left:0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:950px)
{
    .span3 {
        width:48%;
        margin-left:4%;
    }

    .span3:nth-child(odd) {
        margin-left:0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) 
{
    .span3 {
        width:100%;
        margin-left:0%;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

**Note** I know there are tons of frameworks with this feature (like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507449/three-column-layout-with-block-of-different-heights)), but if possible I would prefer to keep my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it out! Super simple and effective.

CSS

```
.span3 {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    border:1px solid;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:951px)
{
    .span3 {
        width:33.3%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:950px)
{
    .span3 {
        width:50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) 
{
    .span3{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Hope it can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Now its working if u use 3 times clear:both but I rly dont know why is needed use there 3x.
http://jsfiddle.net/LmPwe/

```
<div class="span3">
<b>ONE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>TWO</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque interdum risus nulla, ac tristique dolor tincidunt consequat. Nunc malesuada pharetra scelerisque.
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>THREE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div><div style="clear:both;"></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="span3">
<b>FOUR</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>FIVE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque interdum risus nulla, ac tristique dolor tincidunt consequat. Nunc malesuada pharetra scelerisque.
</div>

<div class="span3">
<b>SIX</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 2.x, you can do this..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
  <b>ONE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
  <b>TWO</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque interdum risus nulla, ac tristique dolor tincidunt consequat. Nunc malesuada pharetra scelerisque.
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
  <b>THREE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="span4">
  <b>FOUR</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
  <b>FIVE</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque interdum risus nulla, ac tristique dolor tincidunt consequat. Nunc malesuada pharetra scelerisque.
  </div>

  <div class="span4">
  <b>SIX</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/120857

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if possible I would like to avoid using frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

i put a row class in each row. here is the code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

and float it left and put margin buttom

whole code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/ndEUS/

Comment: I can't do this, since when I have 2 columns, this 3-blocks structure is not valid anymore. In 2-columns layout I should align 1-2 and 3-4 and 5-6 and this is not achievable with your structure. Thanks anyway.